# Variable capturing in string literal in Go?

Tags: syntax, go, string-interpolation

In Ruby, I could directly capture variables in string literals like in `bash`.

```
SRCDIR  =   "aaa"
DSTDIR  =   "bbb"

puts "SRCDIR = #{SRCDIR}"
puts "DSTDIR = #{DSTDIR}"
```

This is a simple and tiny feature, but very nice to make it feel like a shell script. If I have to write a complex shell script this helps a lot because this eliminates the need for substitution, concatenation and format expression.

Does Go have something like this? If it does, how to use it?

Comment: Go does not aim to be a scripting language.

Comment: Check out the package `text/template` if you are looking to produce parameterized text.

Answer (score 5):

Not without a formatting string; the usual way to do this is with `fmt.Printf` or `fmt.Sprintf`:

```
srcdir := "aaa"
dstdir := "bbb"

// separated out Sprintf and Println for clarity
fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("SRCDIR = %s", srcdir))
fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("DSTDIR = %s", dstdir))

// could be shortened if you're just printing them
fmt.Printf("SRCDIR = %s\n", srcdir)
fmt.Printf("DSTDIR = %s\n", dstdir)
```

Comment: Also worth noting that you can specify index positions in your string and not format in the exact same order of your parameters. e.g. - `fmt.Printf("dstdir=%[2]s srcdir=%[1]s", srcdir, dstdir)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to concat with the + operator as in JS

main.go

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    movieQuote := `"What's the most you ever lost on a coin toss?"`
    statement := `Back-ticks allow double quotes, ` + movieQuote + `, and single quote apostrophe's`

    fmt.Println("movieQuote: ", movieQuote)
    fmt.Println("statement: ", statement)
}
```

Run

```sh
go run main.go
```

Output:

```sh
movieQuote:  "What's the most you ever lost on a coin toss?"
statement:  Back-ticks allow double quotes, "What's the most you ever lost on a coin toss?", and single quote apostrophe's
```

Answer (score 0):

What Wes said.  I should add that if you're using custom types, you might define a method which has the signature `String() string` on them (to essentially make them satisfy the [`fmt.Stringer`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) interface) and then pass instances of these types directly to functions of the `fmt` package which expect a string, such as `fmt.Println()`.  A simple introduction to this might be found in ["Effective Go"](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces).

Answer (score 0):

### GQL Queries

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/gookit/color"
)

const (
    offerInfo string = `{
        id
        name
        description
        logoURL
        opt_ins {
          id
          name
          description
        }
      }`
)

func QueryAllOffers() string {
    return `{ offer ` + offerInfo + `}`
}

func QueryOfferByID(id string) string {
    return `{
        offer (id: "` + string(id)  + `")` + offerInfo + ` }`
}

func main() {
    queryAllOffers := QueryAllOffers()
    color.Cyan.Println(queryAllOffers)

    offerID := "0001"
    queryOfferByID := QueryOfferByID(offerID)
    color.Blue.Println(queryOfferByID)
}
```

#### Output: queryAllOffers

```
{
  offer {
    id
    name
    description
    logoURL
    opt_ins {
      id
      name
      description
    }
  }
}
```

#### Output: queryOfferById

```
{
  offer(id: "0001") {
    id
    name
    description
    logoURL
    opt_ins {
      id
      name
      description
    }
  }
}
```